# Ada83 Unchecked Conversion of Record in Declaration

Tags: ada

I want to declare a constant as a 16 bit integer of type Word and assign a value to it. To support portability between Big and Little Endian platforms, I can't safely use an assignment like this one:

```
Special_Value : Constant Word := 16#1234#;
```

because the byte order might be misinterpreted.

So I use a record like this:

```
   Type Double_Byte Is Record
      Byte_1 : Byte; -- most significant byte
      Byte_0 : Byte; -- least significant byte
   End Record;
   For Double_Byte Use Record
      Byte_1 At 0 Range 0..7;  
      Byte_0 At 0 Range 8..15; 
   End Record;
```

However, in some cases, I have a large number of pre-configuration assignments that look like this:

```
Value_1 : Constant Word := 15#1234#;
```

This is very readable by a person, but endian issues cause it to be misunderstood a number of ways (including in the debugger, for example).

Because I have many lines where I do this, I tried the following because it is fairly compact as source code. It is working, but I'm not sure why, or what part of the Ada Reference Manual covers this concept:

```
Value_1 : Constant Word := DByte_To_Word((Byte_1 => 16#12#, 
                                           Byte_0 => 16#34#));
```

where DByte_To_Word  is defined as

```
Function DByte_To_Word          Is New Unchecked_Conversion(Double_Byte, Word);
```

I think I have seen something in the ARM that allows me to do this, but not the way I described above. I can't find it and I don't know what I would be searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s nothing unusual about your call to `DByte_To_Word`; `(Byte_1 => 16#12#, Byte_0 => 16#34#)` is a perfectly legitimate record aggregate of type `Double_Byte`, see [LRM83 4.3.1](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83lrm/html/lrm-04-03.html#4.3.1).

But! But! it’s true that, on a big-endian machine, the first (lowest-addressed) byte of your `Word` will contain `16#12#`, whereas on a little-endian machine it will contain `16#34#`. The CPU takes care of all of that; if you print the value of `Special_Value` you will get `16#1234#` (or `0x1234`) no matter which endianness the computer implements.

The only time you’ll encounter endianness issues is when you’re copying binary data from one endianness to another, via the network, or a file.

If your debugger gets confused about this, you need a better debugger!